# Android show overlay view at a specific location

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to show an overlay view at some specific bound in screen ( like `Rect(30,60,200, 400)`). My code always gives a fullscreen overlay view, not the desired rect with specific top left, width, height.
My layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#50018786"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Main Activity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static int ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 5469;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && !Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION);
            startActivity(myIntent);
        } else {
            onAuthorizedOverlay();
        }
    }

    private void onAuthorizedOverlay() {
        Button button = findViewById(R.id.inflate_button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY,
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN,
                        PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
                );
//                params.x = 30; // these code have no effect 
//                params.y = 60;
//                params.width = 170;
//                params.height = 340;
                Rect r = new Rect(30,60,200, 400);
                WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
                LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                RelativeLayout mTopView = (RelativeLayout)  li.inflate(R.layout.my_overlay, null);

                windowManager.addView(mTopView, params);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (!Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
                // You don't have permission

            } else {
                // Do as per your logic
                onAuthorizedOverlay();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I noticed that the commented code I made for `params` has no effect.
How can I show an overlay view at a certain rect?

Comment: Why you're creating overlay on the window level any specific reason?

Comment: I want to make some annotation/explanation view

Comment: No need window level you can use parent layout itself...

Comment: Try showcase libraries..

Answer (score 0):

You are not using mentioned rectangle anywhere.

Check this out.

```
private void onAuthorizedOverlay() {
    Button button = findViewById(R.id.inflate_button);
    button.setOnClickListener(view -> {
        WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        RelativeLayout mTopView = (RelativeLayout) li.inflate(R.layout.my_overlay, null);

        WindowManager.LayoutParams overlayParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE |
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL |
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN);

        overlayParams.height = 100;
        overlayParams.width = 200;
        overlayParams.x = 300;
        overlayParams.y = 400;

        windowManager.addView(mTopView, overlayParams);
    });
}
```

Comment: HI Andrei I tried your code but the origin for (left, top) is not positioned correctly. A (left,top) of (300, 400) as in your code is on the lower right corner of the screen. When I tried to set ``` overlayParams.x = 0;
                overlayParams.y = 0;``` I see that the top left origin is at the middle of the screen. How can I fix the code?

Comment: I tried with the given code but it did not work. it always shows in the center position.